# Python OpenCV crashes when trying to read a video

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

When I am calling the `.read()` method then my program crashes (with .avi format). My program runs with other formats (.ogv, .mkv) but in that case `type(last_frame) == None`. Is there any solution to fix these errors?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

in_file = r'C:\Users\Johnny\Desktop\zola\animation.avi'
print(in_file)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(in_file)
print(cap)
ret, last_frame = cap.read() # the program works without this line

try:
    if not cap.isOpened() : raise("damn!")
except TypeError as err:
    print(err)
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\Johnny\Desktop\zola\animation.ogv
<VideoCapture 02843110>
exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not str
```

Comment: sorry for the recent sloppyness:  please add a check: if not cap.isOpened() : raise Exception("damn!") (also do that before trying to read anything)

Comment: also, since you're on win, try to find out, which exact compression method is used inside your avi(that is just a container), and install the respective codec, i.e from here: http://fourcc.org/

Comment: It worked, please type an answer and i can accept it